# Int id vs. varchar id

Tags: mysql, int

Which type of id is better for querying and to use as foreign key in mysql:

1)Varchar id with size 20

2)Int id

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An int is usually better, because it gives better performance.

If your item has a [natural key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) which is a varchar, you could use that and it will work. But you will get a performance  improvement (and some other benefits) by adding a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) that is an integer. You can add an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Int IDS are more efficient because the database will only have to compare once.

So lets say you have `n` rows. If you use an `int` then you're looking at `O(n)` as a worst case. Where as if you use a `varchar(20)` you're looking at `O(n*20)`

Comment: `O(n*20)` is exactly the same as `O(n)`. You can't use big-O notation to express a constant factor difference.

Comment: @MarkByers It all depends on the definition and the common understanding. According to wikipedia and what i've learned in universit  what you are describing is a simplification of the term which is permitted in Big-O notation. But it is also no problem to put the constant factor in, because here we are in the context of a practical application (an implementation) and we only have a linear term (x instead of x^2 or x^3) and so a factor of 20 or not twenty is extremely relevant. So i'd say here it is beneficial and relevant to the understanding to point out the difference.

Answer (score 0):

INT IDs are always preferable..

It is faster and uses less storage on the database.

There are cases when VARCHAR IDs are needed, but INT is more efficient